# How to not show returned data when GET api called from browser address bar in React.js + Node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, http-post, http-get

I have a GET api that returns some json data when called.

How do I prevent people trying to access this get api url directly on the browser address bar from seeing what the api is supposed to return without using POST api?

I mean, instead of using POST api, what should I do to not show what is returned when the GET api called through the browser address bar?

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra header like Authorization/Header.
So that Only the if a valid Authorization token is passed than the data will be displayed.
This will make your API endpoint more secure and only authorized user can get data.